# how php function preg_match_all outputs matches array

Tags: php

```
<?php
// The \\2 is an example of backreferencing. This tells pcre that
// it must match the second set of parentheses in the regular expression
// itself, which would be the ([\w]+) in this case. The extra backslash is
// required because the string is in double quotes.
$html = "<b>bold text</b><a href=howdy.html>click me</a>";

preg_match_all("/(<([\w]+)[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/\\2>)/", $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $val) {
    echo "matched: " . $val[0] . "\n";
    echo "part 1: " . $val[1] . "\n";
    echo "part 2: " . $val[2] . "\n";
    echo "part 3: " . $val[3] . "\n";
    echo "part 4: " . $val[4] . "\n\n";
}
?>
```

In this example first it finds matches using a pattern and put them inside matches array. But i could not understand how it finds the parts(val[0],val[1],......)(basically no idea about what is part)

Comment: why don't you `var_dump($matches);`? That will show you how the array is structured.

Answer (score 2):

Quite simple: index 0 holds the entire string that matched and, from 1 to N, you have the various capturing groups you defined.

So, given the regex `/(<([\w]+)[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/\\2>)/`, group 1 will contain the whole opening tag, group 2 the specific tag name, group 3 the tag content and group 4 the closing tag.

For example:

```
$html = "<b>bold text</b>";

preg_match_all("/(<([\w]+)[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/\\2>)/", $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

// here we have
// $matches[0] == "<b>bold text</b>";
// $matches[1] == "<b>";
// $matches[2] == "b";
// $matches[3] == "bold text";
// $matches[4] == "</b>";
```

As always, see also [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

> If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search.
>   `$matches[0]` will contain the text that matched the full pattern,
>   `$matches[1]` will have the text that matched the first captured
>   parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

`$val[0]` is the part of the string that matches the entire `regex`. The parts from `1` to `4` are the substrings that match the capturing groups in your `regex`. The capturing groups are delimited by parentheses (`(` and `)`) and they are counted from left to right by their opening parenthesis.

```
/(<([\w]+)[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/\\2>)/
 ^ ^             ^    ^
 1 2             3    4
```

I marked above the open parenthesis of each group. The groups are:

```
1: (<([\w]+)[^>]*>)
2: ([\w]+)
3: (.*?)
4: (<\/\\2>)
```

As you can see, group #2 is embedded in group #1 and this means `$val[2]` will be a substring of `$val[1]` (`strpos($val[1], $val[2]) !== FALSE`). Also, because group#4 contains a backreference to group #2, the value returned in `$val[2]` will be a substring of `$val[4]`.

For more explanation about how a `regex` is constructed read the PHP documentation about [`PCRE Patterns`](http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php).